# Update theme of select by classname

Tags: jquery-mobile

The following works for all buttons and selects (jqm 1.2).  Page theme is data-theme-a.How do I get it to work for **specific selects** on the page where the class name is **cc_group**?

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_setup', function (event, ui) {
            var theme = 'e';
            //the only difference between this block of code and the same code above is that it doesn't target list-dividers by calling: `.not('.ui-li-divider')`
            $.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-btn').not('.ui-li-divider')
                    .removeClass('ui-btn-a')
                    .addClass('ui-btn-up-' + theme)
                    .attr('data-theme', theme);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This works!  For those looking for the answer, the key is the div that houses the select (classname ui-select).  Then ui-btn-up is the jqm button that is styled.

```
$(".cc_group").closest("div").addClass('ui-btn-up-' + theme).attr("data-theme", "e").removeClass("ui-btn-hover-a").removeClass("ui-btn-up-a");
```